# Is there any difference in the position of data declaration in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, boot

I have the following code:

```
[org 0x7c00]
string : db "hello", 0

mov ah , 0x0e  
mov al , "j"
int 0x10 
jmp $

times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 0x55 , 0xaa
```

For some reason the character is not printed. When I define the string after the interrupt, the program works fine.

What is the matter with this?

I'm using the following commands:

```
nasm -fbin boot2.asm -o boot2.iso && qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,file=boot2.iso
```

Comment: Do not put data in the execution path. To the cpu bytes are bytes, if you put them in the way, the cpu will try to execute them as instructions.

Comment: The first problem is thinking of this as anything so fancy as a "declaration".  Assembly is simpler and more brutal than higher-level languages.  `db` means "put these bytes in the output, right here, right now".

Comment: i guess then those bites cause some malfunction  . i thought of it more like this: the cpu will execute some irrelevant code , and then will proceed executing the mov ah , 0xe  etc  ... but probably was really not good setting those bits in that place . thanks :)